# ¿Cómo leer y escribir en una RFID mediante puerto serial en C#?

Tags: c#

¡Qué tal!

Estoy en proceso de desarrollar una aplicación en C# que utiliza una antena UHF para leer y escribir en RFID's. Esta antena utiliza el puerto serial.
Busqué arduamente en internet cómo comunicarme con el puerto serial y casi todos utilizaban el mismo método: SerialPort. Usando éste método le envié un comando a la antena que viene tal cual en el manual, pero la respuesta es totalmente diferente.

Este es el código que hice:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace TagDetector
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            mySerialPort.Open();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mySerialPort.Write("'CSE      '<LF><CR>");
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += mySerialPort_DataReceived;
        }

        void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.Write("Data Received:");
            Console.WriteLine(indata);
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            mySerialPort.Close();
            mySerialPort.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es la salida que me da:

```
----------------------------------
Data Received:7?8?V7?7?7?7?7?7?7?
```

Los símbolos que parecen una T al revés no aparecen en la consola, me imagino que porque no son imprimibles.

Este es el manual del dispositivo:

[image: Manual]

No es problema de la RFID, ya que el software con el que viene la antena si la detecta, lee y escribe perfectamente.
Espero puedan ayudarme, llevo desde ayer buscando por todos lados y nada más no encuentro solución.

Gracias de antemano.
¡Saludos!

Comment: Hola @Emmanuel, bienvenido a [es.So]. ¿Podrías poner tu código como texto? ... Y si "*la respuesta es totalmente diferente*", ¿qué respuesta estás recibiendo y cuál es la esperada?

Comment: Solo como pista...Cuando en el manual se describe que debes enviar `<LF><CR>`,no significa que debas enviar eso como texto, si no mas  bien algo como `Environment.NewLine`, o mejor `"\x0d\x0a"`

Comment: Qué tal, Mariano y Pikoh.
Ya edité mi pregunta con el código y respuesta que me da.
En cuanto al `<LF><CR>`, ya había intentado otras alternativas antes como las mencionadas, pero sigue sin darme la respuesta esperada.
La respuesta que se supone debería darme, es la que aparece en la imagen del manual, la segunda flecha.
¡Muchas gracias por sus comentarios!

Comment: Hace tiempo trabajé con hardware que enviaba comandos a dispositivos bluetooth, dichos comandos tenian que estar escritos en hexadecimal. Para entender mejor esos <LF><CR> Dale una lectura a este enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1552749/3613462 éxitos con el proyecto :D y bienvenido a SOes!

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! De hecho sí tenían que estar en hexadecimal.